# Copying Customers/Orders between Magento installations

Tags: data-migration

I need to copy a subset of customers and orders from one Magento installation to another. While copying new entity IDs must be assigned thus existing ones are not overwritten.

What would be your suggested way of doing it?

This is M2 but I guess an approach would be the same for M1 also.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

I do not recommend you do it manually by exporting/importing the tables, because you will get problems with the difference of attribute IDs. I believe this is the best solution for you: [Magento to Magento migration](https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/).

Comment: I did not do it, but my guess is the downvote is probably because this is recommending a commercial solution (and this is extremely expensive tool too). However, the premise is correct and a migration tool is pretty much required. Orders use TONS of tables, especially if you want to include history like shipping, invoice, credit memo, etc.

Comment: @PhilM Same thinking :). Most people here hate the commercial solutions although sometimes they are essential. Thanks Phil.